# Factoring $f(x)=3x^4+14x^3+21x^2+10x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

How should I go about factoring $f(x)=3x^4+14x^3+21x^2+10x$

I tried factoring out a $x$, and then factoring by grouping, but that led me to no avail.

I used a polynomial calculator and it gave me the answer without any of the steps as to how they did it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Assuming that you haven't studied the solutions to cubic or quartic equations, and assuming that it was intended that you notice that $(x=0)$ is a root of the equation, the **real** question is *what did the questioner intend*?  Personally, I would say that it is 50-50 whether you were supposed to immediately swim in the lake of the rational root theorem, or whether you were (instead) supposed to immediately notice and attach significance to the fact that $(3 + 21) = (14 + 10).$

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem called the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) which states that all rational roots of an integer polynomial are of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ is a factor of the constant term and $q$ is a factor of the leading coefficient, when neither are equal to $0$. You already got that $$f(x) = x(3x^3 + 14x^2 + 21x + 10)$$

Then the rational roots of the second term must be in $\left\{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 10, \pm \frac{1}{3}, \pm \frac{2}{3}, \pm \frac{5}{3}, \pm \frac{10}{3} \right\}$. Once you go through this list and find a root $r$, you can factor out $x-r$. For example, with the root $x=-2$, the equation becomes $$f(x)=x(x+2)(3x^2+8x+5)$$

The last term can be factored, with the quadratic formula, by simply recognizing that $3+5 = 8$ and thus $x+1$ would be a factor, or by continuing to go through the possible list of rational roots. Ultimately, it would factor out to $$f(x)=x(x+2)(x+1)(3x+5)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Notice that $f(0) = f(-1) = 0$. Taking advantage of such facts, one has
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 3x^{4} + 14x^{3} + 21x^{2} + 10x\\\\
& = x(3x^{3} + 14x^{2} + 21x +10)\\\\
& = x[(3x^{3} + 3x^{2}) + (11x^{2} + 11x) + (10x + 10)]\\\\
& = x[3x^{2}(x+1) + 11x(x+1) + 10(x+1)]\\\\
& = x(x+1)(3x^{2} + 11x + 10)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this. So plugging in -1 results in zero, so that allows us to factor out an x-1(if I'm understanding right)? I'm not sure that I understand how you are able to separate the second line where you have (3x^3+3x^2)+(11x^2+11x) ... can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @IsabelleKreienbrink If $f$ is a polynomial and $f(a)=0$ for some number $a$, then $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$. This can be proved using the "Remainder Theorem".

Comment: the discriminant of $3 x^2 + 11 x + 10$ is $1.$ Perhaps that is what "Can you take it from here?" refers to..

Answer (score 0):

Answer :
f(-1)=0⇒f(x) = (x+1)(3x³+11x²+10x)
⇒f(x) = x(x+1)(3x^2 +11x+10)

On pose h(x) = 3x^2 +11x+10

⇒f(x) =x(x+1)(h(x))

h(-2)=0⇒ h(x) =(x+2)(3x+5)

Finally :
⇒ f(x) = x(x+1)(x+2)(3x+5)

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha can often show you factors in alternate forms as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E4%2B14x%5E3%2B21x%5E2%2B10x) about a third of the way down the page.

Another way of finding $1$ of the solutions to a cubic equation is to use the cubic formula;

$$x=\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{b}{3a}$$

where, for $\quad(3x^3 + 14x^2 + 21x + 10)\qquad a=3\quad b=14\quad c=21\quad d=10$
\begin{equation}
x=\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-(14)^3}{27(3)^3 }+\frac{(14)(21)}{6(3)^2}-\frac{(10)}{2(3)}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-(14)^3}{27(3)^3}+\frac{(14)(21)}{6(3)^2}-\frac{(10)}{2(3)}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{(21)}{3(3)}-\frac{(14)^2}{9(3)^2}\biggr)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-(14)^3}{27(3)^3 }+\frac{(14)(21)}{6(3)^2}-\frac{(10)}{2(3)}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-(14)^3}{27(3)^3}+\frac{(14)(21)}{6(3)^2}-\frac{(10)}{2(3)}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{(21)}{3(3)}-\frac{(14)^2}{9(3)^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{(14)}{3(3)}
\end{equation}

I haven't tried this in Excel or with Wolfram Alpha because it takes to loog to remove the things \frac{}{}, \bigg,  \sqrt[]{}, etc that go into making it. It has worked when I plugged in numbers from other equations even when I had transient complex numbers where I needed robust software like Wolfram Alpha to resolve them.